# HTTP_REFERER not displaying anything

Tags: php, http-referer, server-variables

I have two websites on two different servers. When I print the following on WEBSITE1 then it displays referrer name (if there is any referrer)

```
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

But same code doesn't work on WEBSITE2. It's just a simple echo nothing else. I know if no referrer is coming then it won't print anything but I have created a test page with link like this:

```
<a href="http://website2">Click</a>
```

But it doesn't display any referrer. No bug no nothing. Both servers are running PHP5. Is there some setting in php.ini through which we can prevent display of HTTP_REFERER?

Thanks

Comment: What server are you using?  Is PHP running as CGI?  FastCGI?  Server extension?

Comment: Are you using the same browser to test both sites?

Comment: Might not be the PHP - 2 different servers, does that mean 2 different Apache installs? If so, one might have something in mod_header doing something the other isn't.

Comment: I cannot check this because I only have access to FTP (this is client's server)

Comment: **What server** are you using?  You didn't answer that question.  What do you see when you `print_r($_SERVER);`?

Comment: @Brad
Here you go. http://pastebin.com/RFvGBn6p

Comment: Can you packet sniff a request that you're expecting referer to be set for?  I suspect that the client isn't sending one.

Comment: @Brad
Not possible because I am using same Chrome browser for both websites. Here is what I did. I entered keyword in Google, it displayed result in which one of the result is WEBSITE1. I click on link, go to WEBSITE1 and it displays referrer as Google. Then I repeat the same procedure with WEBSITE2 but it doesn't display referrer. Same browser, same PC.

Comment: @Ali, Post a packet trace.  I'm not convinced.

Comment: http://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: @Brad
Here you go. http://pastie.org/3689663

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using document.referrer of Javascript. Don't know what's wrong with HTTP_REFERER though.